# set ListView on setOnClickListener whit ID

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have `listView` which show image and text from MySQL DB. So far is ok but now I wonder how to make if some item is clicked to open that ID from database. Example `ListView 1` is with `id=1` from database ..`ListView 2` is with `id=2` and so on. When I click on item 2 to open that ID from DB. Any idea how can I do this?
This is xml which load the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the part of code which I believe I need to fix

```
public class Restaurants extends Activity {

ListView listView;
TextView textView, textView1;
private StockAdaptor stockAdaptor;
String jsonResult = null;
ImageView image;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurants); //Just a listView, shown below
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    new JsonReadTask().execute("http://link/GetRestaurants.php");



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(listView.getLayoutParams());
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
    listView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Restaurants.this, RestaurantInformation.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true; //No options
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    stockAdaptor = new StockAdaptor(this); //Create a new StockAdaptor
}

public static String strFromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException { //Simple function, getting a String from an InputStream
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String cline;
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((cline = breader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(cline);
        out.append(newLine);
    }
    return out.toString();
}

private class StockAdaptor extends BaseAdapter { //The stocks list adaptor

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        //TextView menu;
        ImageView image; 
    }

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RestaurantStrings[] stocks = null; //Array of stocks
    private ListView stocksListView = null;

    public StockAdaptor(Context context) {
        super();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setStockList(RestaurantStrings[] stocksinfo) {
        this.stocks = stocksinfo;// //////////////LITERALLY THIS

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stocks.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stocks[position];
    }
    public RestaurantStrings[] getAll() { //Return the array of stocks
        return stocks;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder; //New holder
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_second, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Creates the new viewHolder define above, storing references to the children
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            //holder.menu = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);



            if (holder.image != null) {
                if (holder.image.getDrawable() == null) {
                    new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image, null)                                 
                    .execute(stocks[position].image); //Download the image using the image

                }
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(stocks[position].name);
        //holder.menu.setText(stocks[position].menu);

        return convertView;
    }
}

private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(params[0])) {
            final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();
                if (httpentity != null){
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = httpentity.getContent();
                        jsonResult = strFromStream(inputStream);
                        Log.i("", jsonResult);
                        return jsonResult;
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        //
                    } finally {
                        httpentity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListDrwaer();
    }

}// end async task

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
    //Log.d("data from server", "data: " + jsonResult.toString());
    try {
        if (jsonResult!=null) {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("restaurants");
            Vector<RestaurantStrings> vstocks = new Vector<RestaurantStrings>();

            if(jsonMainNode == null)
            {
                Log.e("If is null", "jsonMainNode is null");
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                RestaurantStrings stock = new RestaurantStrings();

                stock.image = jsonChildNode.getString("image");
                stock.name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                //stock.menu = jsonChildNode.optString("menu");

                //stock.imgPath = jsonChildNode.getString("imgPath");

               Log.e("err", stock.image + " " + stock.name);
               vstocks.add(stock);
            }

            RestaurantStrings[] stocks = new RestaurantStrings[jsonMainNode.length()];

            int stockscount = jsonMainNode.length();
            for (int n = 0; n < stockscount; n++) 
            {               
                stocks[n] = vstocks.get(n);
            }
            stockAdaptor.setStockList(stocks);
            listView.setAdapter(stockAdaptor);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error; jsonResult null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, View view) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }

        }

    }

    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){

            final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                            + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                    return null;
                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        try {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                            int bytesRead;
                            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }   
                            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.toByteArray().length);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            return null;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                    client.close();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

If I try to put in `onCreate()` one `setOnClickListener` as you can see the app gives `"Unfortunately your app has stopped"`

UPDATE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity" 
android:background="#D3D3D3">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error

```
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): Process: com.reserveme, PID: 1493
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reserveme/com.reserveme.Restaurants}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.reserveme.Restaurants.onCreate(Restaurants.java:69)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-05 13:37:26.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: exception stacktrace?

Comment: There is no Listview in your layout file. Maybe that layout is the listview item? If so add the correct layout to your question. If not then you already know what's missing

Comment: Sorry I forget to add it when I post question. I've updated it now.

Comment: @guido, I've added also `logcat`

Comment: and Restaurants.java line 69 is where?

Comment: you initilialized `textview1` but not `textView`. Then you try to reference `textView` which can only be null.

Comment: Line 69 -> `textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: But if I put `textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` instead of `textview1` I get same result.

Comment: in the snippet in the question you have `textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`. please post the actual code with the corresponding stacktraces

Comment: @guido, I've posted full code of `restaurants,java`

Comment: according to update, you don't have a TextView in your xml resource

Comment: But I have in the first xml in my question. I want/tried this `textView` to make? Or I'm totally messed this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using a ListView in one of my projects too. To get the touched/clicked position in my listview I have registered a ClickHandler to the ListView (not to the items of the list).
In your example the ID is equal to the position, so I think you could do the same.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Restaurants.this, RestaurantInformation.class);
            intent.putExtra("myID", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

In the new Activity you can call the following to get the id:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        myID = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("myID");
    }
```

Comment: I can't figured out how to link the item with the ID on click\

Comment: I've tried with `Intent intent = new Intent(Restaurants.this, RestaurantInformation.class); startActivity(intent);` And actually it open new activity and doesn't crash. The question is how to take the corresponded ID and when it open second activity to load info for that ID. The ID is equal to the position in the listview

Comment: You can put the ID with `intent.putExtra("id", theID)` and get it with `if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
   idFromIntent = (String) intent.getExtras().get("id");
  }`

Comment: This in `onItemClick` block?

Comment: I don't get how to call it from second activity. In `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes in `onCreate()` of the second activity.

Comment: Now is `Cannot cast from Object to int` on this line `myID = (int) intent.getExtras().get("myID");`

Comment: Almost there but doesn't load info for the clicked ID. Do I need to connect here again to database and make query because is empty page and for `myID` is `The value of the local variable myID is not used`

Comment: Yes or you have to save the data in a way you can access it from your second activity

Comment: save info like in `intent.putExtra("name", name); intent.putExtra("image", image);` and then I get them `extras.getString("name"); ... etc`?

Comment: For example. Or connect again

Comment: May be is better to connect again. Thank's for your help. I think this post is done.

Comment: But if I connect again and fetch info how will know that must give me the `ID` which is clicked?